# Is there a way to search for a key in a .txt file and update its value in Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x

EDIT: I took Jighdan's advice and started using JSON files. It seems to be working! The operations you can do with the json package include a lot of what I needed. Thanks for the answers everyone!

For example, I have a file that looks like this.

```
C1:40,36
C2:20,30
C3:22,2
C4:15,33
```

I want to be able to receive data like C3:21,40 and search the file for C3 and update it so the file looks like this.

```
C1:40,36
C2:20,30
C3:21,40
C4:15,33
```

If the key does not exist, for example I receive C5:32,11, it adds a new line like this.

```
C1:40,36
C2:20,30
C3:22,2
C4:15,33
C5:32,11
```

Is this possible in Python 3.7?

The closest I've gotten is this. But it updates the whole line.

```
import fileinput  
text_to_search = 'hello'  
replacement_text = 'good by'  
with fileinput.FileInput('TEST.txt', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:     
     for line in file:         
          print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

Comment: A for text in and replace sub or full text should work! What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten 

`import fileinput

text_to_search = 'hello'

replacement_text = 'good by'

with fileinput.FileInput('TEST.txt', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')`

But it replaces the whole text. Not update the value like I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible. You text file already has the form of a dictionary, so when reading it, just put the data in a dictionary. Then you can easily replace or add keys to the dictionary, and write the dictionary back to file in original string format.

Something like this:

```
input = 'C3:32,11'

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    # build dictionary
    d = {}
    for str in f.readlines():
        key, value  = str.split(':')
        d[key] = value.strip()
    ikey, ivalue = input.split(':')     # user input also has to be split
    d[ikey] = ivalue.strip()

with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    # stringify
    for key, value in d.items():
        f.write(':'.join([key, value]) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

My own way:

```
checker = 'C6:32,11'
present = False
new_file = []

with open('change.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if checker[:2] == line[:2] and checker[3:] is not line[3:]:
                new_file.append(line.replace(line[3:].strip('\n'), checker[3:]))
                present = True
        else:
            new_file.append(line)

with open('change.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(new_file)
    if not present:
        f.writelines('\n')
        f.writelines(checker)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with use of [lambda](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function) and [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

```
input = 'C3:32,11'

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    head = lambda x: x[0:x.find(':')]  # get head of line from 0 to position of :
    # use if ... else list comprehension and save output in box
    box = [input + '\n' if head(line) == head(input) else line for line in f.readlines()]

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    [f.write(line) for line in box]  # overwrite test.txt with content of box
```